# Naming feature module packages

Tags: android

In a multi-module project where the package name of the 'app' module is:

`com.example.app`

Should additional 'feature modules' *add on* to this package name, like so:

**A)** `com.example.app.feature`

Or is it okay to omit the app name (default behavior of Android Studio):

**B)** `com.example.feature`

---

Are there potential conflicts down the road if I publish two apps with feature modules that have the same package name (because I omitted the app name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the feature module, I think to use `com.company.app.feature` will more clearly. Because of one app maybe have multiple features module like: `com.company.app.feature1`, `com.company.app.feature2`. And these feature modules belong to one app.

---

But with the library module, set to `com.company.feature` (app name not included) will be better. Because the library is independence, it doesn't belong to one specified app. A library can be implemented in multiple apps, like when you implement library on Github.
 
Ex: You make a library to draw statistic chart with a custom view and named with package name: `com.yourname.chart`, you can keep developing it, any app can implement it to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with what you said here. I'll leave the question open as I'm still curious if there's any risk involved with the second method (`com.company.feature`).

Comment: I like this idea, but prefer to also add "module" ( `com.company.module.feature` and `com.company.app.module.feature` ). This makes it clearer what's a module, and also leaves the address space free for other apps or packages that may want to use the same name as some modules (you may want to have part of the feature implemented directly in your app module, but still keep it in its own package. Or you may want to have "utils" both as a module and as a package in "app" - I prefer if these two have different package names)